# Spring trying to extract beans from different places

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

The error is actually a Conflicting persistence unit, which is something defined in a component, which is a parent for my project. My spring context is taking that conflicting unit from both the target/classes folder of the component and the jar stored in the local maven repository as well. Why is this happening? This is the error trace:

```
Error creating bean with name 'persistenceUnitManager' defined in class 
path resource [spring-config/framework-persistence-context.xml]: Invocation 
of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Conflicting persistence unit definitions for name 'persistence-framework':
file:/D:/fw/projects/springproj-core-project/springproj-core-framework/target/classes,     
file:/C:/Users/prateek.chachra/.m2/repository/com/springproj/
springproj-core-framework/1.4.M1/springproj-core-framework-1.4.M1.jar
```

Comment: show us your relevant configurations and project structure

Comment: I'm trying to run springproj-web-proj which is built over springproj-core-framework.The persistence unit is defined only once, but it is being picked during the build from both the target classes and the class stored in the maven repository.